# Open inner page of other application by bypassing login

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a situation in my project where we are rewriting the existing application to make it adaptable to tablet devices.

I need to point to an page of existing version of application, until the new version is created. The existing application is deployed on separate domain.

I am able to launch the existing application from new one by passing encoded url parameters and able to reach the home page.

However I want to launch a inner page directly without making user to land on home page and navigate to inner page.

If I fire the inner page URL directly, the existing application does not support this and throws exception.

I existing app is developed by an another vendor and client does not have budget to start some development there to support this requirement out of the box.

**URL1: to login to application**

http://xxx/app2/?D=4OlzhY03ap19R7RA3hynX0B&dealerCode=E39DEEF760E709&U=CEFE3539DA6563&module=&UT=C96EB15332510B&accessLevel=NONE

**URL2: To open the inner page**

http://xxx/app2/search.do?finalPage=leases&lm_CategoryId=11&lm_SubCategoryId=193

One way I have achieved this is that I first open URL1 in browser and after delay of 5 sec, I open second URL. This works because the browser already have the cookies.

Is there any way I can programatically get the cookies from URL1 and pass on the cookies to open the URL2 in browser.

Please let me know how to implement such that URL2 can be opened without fail.

Kindly let me know if some other details required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should use a fully-covering `<iframe>` on your new page. The browser won't leave the new page but the `iframe` element will load the inner page for the user to use as if it was the current page. It would also have access to the browser cookies. Just set the `src` to the inner page URL and use the following CSS:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 999;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border: 0;
overflow: auto;
```

Be aware that because it is on the new page, the browser's URL bar would still be the new page URL, not the `iframe`'s URL, even while navigating inside the `iframe`. The user also can't see the URL of the `iframe`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe